# English translation of a philosophical quote from Spinoza in Latin

Tags: spinoza, philosophy

*Notandum, dari necessario unius cujusque rei existentis certam aliquam CAUSAM, propter quam existit. Et notandum, hanc causam, propter quam aliqua res existit, vel debere contineri in ipsa natura et DEFINITIONE [15]rei existentis (nimirum quod ad ipsius naturam pertinet existere), vel debere EXTRA ipsam dari.*

Found this in Schopenhauer's "On the Fourfold Root of the Principle of Sufficient Reason".

Could someone translate this to English ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you struggling to understand some specific part of the text? Was there any explanation or translation alongside that passage where you found it? Why are some words written in capitals? You can always edit your question to add details. I think it would be best if the question contained a question rather than just a request to translate. At least it would be easier to answer if you could clarify your goal.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta
Thanks for the comment. This piece of text is part of a philosophical paragraph. After this piece, the author (or translator) explains it in English. I just want the literal meaning of this piece of text. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Notandum* "to be noted"  ( compare: *memorandum* 'to be remembered')

This is followed by indirect speech: 'that...' with Accusative *certam aliquam causam* 'some sure CAUSE;' and Infinitive, *dari necessario* 'be necessarily given' :

> To be noted: that of every single  existing thing whatsoever a sure cause be necessarily given, whereby it exists. And, to be noted: this cause, whereby ( *propter quam* ) any ( *aliqua* ) thing  exists....

*vel debere in.... vel debere extra....* "either ought to be within..."  "or ought to be outside..." The explanation continues in Accusative and Infinitive construction of indirect speech, the object of 'to be noted.'

> ...either ought to be contained within the very nature and  definition of the existent thing (indisputably *nimirum* because *quod*  it pertains to the nature of itself  *pertinet ad ipsius naturam* to exist *existere* ), or it (meaning 'the cause') ought to be given outside of itself.